# Send additional information over HTTP header

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I have written a simple HTTP server using Java and want to send some additional information (puzzle parameters and a small puzzle solver program) to the client i.e. a regular browser.

Similarly, the browser is also supposed to send information (solution) back to the server.

Is there a way to do this by just transmitting this information over the HTTP headers?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could use cookies...though generally, such information is sent in the body as opposed the header. Is there a reason you want to use headers to send the info?

Answer (score 3):

the headers are usually used to add http protocol relevant information.
You should probably use either the body of the response or cookies to add the needed information.
Adding a cookie is done using the header so it kind of fits what you are asking for.

But I wonder why you need to put it in the header? it seems like what you are asking for is url parameters (client to server) and response body (server to client).

Comment: There is no particular reason why I want to use headers. I was just exploring different options to exchange information between the server and client. The client (browser) should be able to process everything within itself, to be precise be as transparent as possible.